# Read_json populates with empty lists; how to remove those rows

Tags: json, pandas

I've got a Pandas dataframe created with pd.read_json(). When I read it in, I get a few cells that have just an empty list or None, and I want to detect the rows with those [], None in certain columns. For example:

```
    feat 1    feat 2    feat 3
0     []        []        5
1     6         8         3
2     None      10        NaN
```

I want to remove rows 0 and 2 because they have None/NaN/empty lists. How can I do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) the `[]` and `None` to `NaN`:

*Note: replace works for the None but not the `[]`... this solution seems to be a little sensitive (hence the use of negation `~`)...*

```
In [11]: df.applymap(lambda x: x == [] or x is None)
Out[11]:
  feat 1 feat 2 feat 3
0   True   True  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False

In [12]: df.where(~df.applymap(lambda x: x == [] or x is None))
Out[12]:
  feat 1 feat 2  feat 3
0    NaN    NaN       5
1      6      8       3
2    NaN     10     NaN
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, and I used it in conjunction with df.dropna().

Comment: @evancchow I posted [an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6518) about the sensitivity of this. Glad it worked for you!